# How do I trigger a Color Attack?

Tags: tetris-axis

When playing in Fever mode, I noticed that sometimes I trigger something called a Color Attack, where all of a sudden the board flips around and has spots for a series of one specific block, which is great for increasing my score.

I have no idea how to make sure I get this, though - it doesn't seem to appear every game, which leads me to wonder what I have to do to make sure I get it.

How do I trigger a Color Attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you clear a full line with the same color tetrimos, you will trigger Color Attack.

Comment: What do you mean, a single line of the same colour? All the tetriminos are different colours....

Comment: Exactly. Create a line using the same colored tetriminos and *poof*  you can start racking up those points.

Answer (score 0):

COLOR ATTACK! Is triggered when you Make a Line of the Same Color, Additionally, on the Right, A Color Bonus will Be Checkmarked for that Color (Any Color that is Checkmarked will Give more Points) The start of the Matrix can help you get an Early Color attack If you're lucky, Sometimes, the Game will provide you with 3 Same Tetriminos Mid-Game so you can trigger color attack, Color Change can help you since it changes the Matrix's Minos into one same color (The tetrimino which comes up next, Respectively).